# How can I choose the SQL schema to write a df?

Tags: database, postgresql, dataframe, sqlalchemy, schema

I am using the following code to upload a df as in a db

```
link=('postgresql://'+user_name+':'+password+'@'+host_name+':5432/postgres')
engine=create_engine(link)
```

I would love to write this df in a selected schema and not in the public schema. How can I do it?

Comment: Can you préfigure your table with the schena as schema.tableName ?

Comment: Include `schema="schema_name"` in your `.to_sql()` call. Details [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html).